# list all installed desktop Environments in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, desktop-environments

I am Using Ubuntu 13.04 and I have installed many desktops environments to try them. Now I want to know is there any way I can list all the installed desktop environments from the command line tool.

Comment: You can read the installed DE list into the login screen. If you try to select a DE you will also see the list of all the installed DEs

Comment: @PeppeDAlterio well , I did mention that already . I want to get from command line.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/xsessions/
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4791 Sep  6 15:45 kde-plasma.desktop
```

[image]

Comment: come on brother , that much fast. some day I will give you complex task. :P

Comment: I have added the image , hope you dont mind.

Comment: 6 minutes isn't really fast for Oli.

Comment: How do we start one of these environments from the command line?

Comment: how to run one of them, manually?