# Keeping only the necessary desktop environment after upgrading to ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: gnome, upgrade, desktop-environments

I upgraded from 16.04 to 20.04.1. However I have been getting a lot of internal error messages. One of the messages was related to **Xwayland**.

Searching for it led me to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347063/list-all-installed-desktop-environments-in-ubuntu) about listing all desktop environments. When I do the same I get 12 with **gnome.desktop** in bold and 4 lines of text-

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/xsessions/
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 231 Apr 10 19:42 gnome-classic.desktop
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 Mar 26  2020 gnome.desktop -> gnome-xorg.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 257 Mar 26  2020 gnome-xorg.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 303 Mar 26  2020 ubuntu.desktop
```

I remember installing `ubuntu.desktop` because after upgrading I didn't get the GUI Login and was stuck with a cursor.

I am okay with gnome, and I was wondering if the 12 others are needed too. Why does it just list 4 in the output?
I'd like to keep only the one I am using now and remove all the others.

**How do I know which one(s) to remove?**

Answer (score 0):

You are able to view other gnome.desktop lines because may be when you tried to solve your previous problem of cursor got stuck, these other supported desktop too got installed.
They all seem to be of gnome.desktop. So I think that those are supportive one.